# Pandas DataFrame to Dict Format with new Keys

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pandas

What would be the best way to convert this:

```
                               deviceid devicetype
0  b569dcb7-4498-4cb4-81be-333a7f89e65f     Google
1  04d3b752-f7a1-42ae-8e8a-9322cda4fd7f    Android
2  cf7391c5-a82f-4889-8d9e-0a423f132026    Android
```

into this:

```
0 {"deviceid":"b569dcb7-4498-4cb4-81be-333a7f89e65f","devicetype":["Google"]}
1 {"deviceid":"04d3b752-f7a1-42ae-8e8a-9322cda4fd7f","devicetype":["Android"]}
2 {"deviceid":"cf7391c5-a82f-4889-8d9e-0a423f132026","devicetype":["Android"]}
```

I've tried df.to_dict() but that just gives:

```
{'deviceid': {0: 'b569dcb7-4498-4cb4-81be-333a7f89e65f',
  1: '04d3b752-f7a1-42ae-8e8a-9322cda4fd7f',
  2: 'cf7391c5-a82f-4889-8d9e-0a423f132026'},
 'devicetype': {0: 'Google', 1: 'Android', 2: 'Android'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apply with `to_json`:

```
In [11]: s = df.apply((lambda x: x.to_json()), axis=1)

In [12]: s[0]
Out[12]: '{"deviceid":"b569dcb7-4498-4cb4-81be-333a7f89e65f","devicetype":"Google"}'
```

To get the list for the device type you could do this manually:

```
In [13]: s1 = df.apply((lambda x: {"deviceid": x["deviceid"], "devicetype": [x["devicetype"]]}), axis=1)

In [14]: s1[0]
Out[14]: {'deviceid': 'b569dcb7-4498-4cb4-81be-333a7f89e65f', 'devicetype': ['Google']}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on on the previous answer `to_dict()` should be a little faster than `to_json()`

This appears to be true for a larger test data frame, but the `to_dict()` method is actually a little slower for the example you provided.

**Large test set**

```
In [1]: %timeit s = df.apply((lambda x: x.to_json()), axis=1)
Out[1]: 100 loops, best of 3: 5.88 ms per loop

In [2]: %timeit s = df.apply((lambda x: x.to_dict()), axis=1)
Out[2]: 100 loops, best of 3: 3.91 ms per loop
```

**Provided example**

```
In [3]: %timeit s = df.apply((lambda x: x.to_json()), axis=1)
Out[3]: 1000 loops, best of 3: 375 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit s = df.apply((lambda x: x.to_dict()), axis=1)
Out[4]: 1000 loops, best of 3: 450 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is because on the way to create a json, to_json creates a dict, ie. basically to_json does str(x.to_dict()). That said to_dict is another good option +1.